# Acceptable Silk to Solder Mask Clearence

Tags: pcb, altium, solder-mask, silkscreen

I am running DRC in Altium Designer and Im getting tons of "Silk to Solder Mask Clearence" Errors. I searched for acceptable values, but without luck. Altium is set to 10mil. I have most values around 7.5mil. Sometimes its even not possible to reduce, for example with an LQFP100 package. What would you suggest me?

Comment: The "acceptable values" will be determined by whoever makes your PCB for you. Contact them (or go to their web site - typically this kind of info is made easily available).

Comment: Why is it not possible to increase the clearance in your footprint design? The silk screen is totally optional. The solder mask holes are not.

Comment: I changed my footprint now according to the info found [here](https://docs.oshpark.com/tips+tricks/stop-mask-expansion/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allowed clearance between silkscreen and soldermask is usually not an issue, but when it is it's determined by the capabilities of your manufacturer. Ultimately the goal is to keep silkscreen ink off of the pads. I generally set my clearance to 0 mil but specify in the fabrication notes that there cannot be any ink on any land, and the supplier may remove conflicting silkscreen at their discretion. Specifying 0.005" (0.127mm) will probably be more than good enough. 0.010" (2.54mm) is ridiculous for a lot of boards, and can be dropped down significantly.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't reduce clearance, you can always remove silkscreen features, or ask your vendor to do it for you.

One vendor that I have a good set of design rules from (but several years old) has 7 mil as standard silk screen registration, with 5 mil available at higher cost. But you should ask your vendor what they can provide.